# Including Natty in Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, natty

I've been trying a variety of ways for the past couple of hours to include Natty (http://natty.joestelmach.com/) into an Android app. I have tried to include JAR files I have compiled from the github repository (https://github.com/joestelmach/natty) but I'm always getting missing class exceptions.

Really stumped on this one, what am I doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up using another library which was not as comprehensive but did the job.

Comment: Sorry for the old post but, what was the library you used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the reason you had issues is that you didn't include all the dependencies of Natty (there are quite a few).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue to, and solved it by downloading all dependencies in form of jar files. 
Please look at this [GitHub issue.](https://github.com/joestelmach/natty/issues/209)